# How to combine react-redux and react-meteor-data in a Meteor 1.3 application?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-redux

How can I use `state` properties from `react-redux` to specify the data that is injected by `react-meteor-data`?

The structure of the `react` component is as follows:

```
  import React from "react";
  import {createContainer} from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
  import {connet} from "react-redux";
  import {Data} from "./data.js"

  class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
           <div>
              {JSON.stringify(this.props.profile)}
           </div>
        );
     }   
  }
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      ID: state.dataId    // ID gets assigned to props here
  });

  export default createContainer(
      () => ({
         profile: Data.findOne({_id: >>>ID<<<})   // ID is needed here
      }), 
      connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
  );
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at React-Komposer, it has functionality for redux as well as meteor trackers.

https://github.com/kadirahq/react-komposer

with komposer you will get two params `props` and `onData`

`props` are the props passed to your container and `onData` is the new props to be sent to the composed component.

Now for connecting both of the systems together, I'm not positive this will work or is the best solution but I'm thinking you could do something like this

`connect(mapStateToProps)(composeWithTacker(onPropsChange)(App))`

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick for the hint! This worked :) Just the order needs to be changed, so that `composeWithTracker` is applied before `connect`. In full length: `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(composeWithTracker(onPropsChange)(App));` with `const onPropsChange = (props, onData) => {const profile = Data.findOne(props.dataId); onData(null, {profile})};`

Comment: Awesome, I am glad to hear that. I'm going to update this in case anyone else has this question.